# Different background color when I copy cells to another workbook

Tags: excel

Sometimes when I copy a cell from one workbook to another it get's a different background color. It could be green in the source cell and become gray in the target cell. Why does this happen?

This happens sometimes when I work on other people's Excel files.

I've thought that maybe it has to do with cell styles. Maybe I copy a cell that is of a certain cell style that is defined on the source sheet but not on the target sheet. But I checked this, and the cell style of the source cell was normal. So the cause must be something else. What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a number of things, most likely:

- the workbooks use different `Page Layout` > `Themes` or `Colors` (See in [Excel 2007/10](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Change-the-default-theme-3b0d77d4-9d33-4bd2-91f9-d95ce39c66b3#bmxl) or [Excel 2013](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Change-a-theme-and-make-it-the-default-c846f997-968e-4daa-b2d4-42bd2afef904#__toc341889144)):
  [image: screenshot of page layout > colors in Excel 2013]
- or there is a [conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Quick-start-Apply-conditional-formatting-6b6f7c2a-5d62-45a1-8f67-584a76776d67) in the original file that no longer matches after copying